# Why the setSelectionRange can't work on android 2.3 platform browser

Tags: javascript, android, selection-api

the code just like [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nicaia/wJVx9/4/)
the code work fine on desktop broswer.
but in android 2.2 or 2.3 browser it has some bugs.
first you use setSelectionRange to set the selection and you can check selectionStart and selectionEnd and it does looks like is work fine.
but it does look like never been set in next time when you check selectionStart or selectionEnd.

Answer (score 3):

wrapping older android browser's setSelectionRange in a setTimeout with an interval of 0 should work. However it doesn't seem to work with Android 3 or better.

see here: [setSelectionRange workaround doesn't work for android 4.0.3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12009015/setselectionrange-workaround-doesnt-work-for-android-4-0-3)

HTH