# Function setSelectionRange is not working in Android browser

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, angularjs, html-input

I am trying to do something like this in a directive in Angularjs. The problem is this works fine in system but when I check the same in Android phone it is failing to set the caret position. I checked on several blogs and website also, is there a solution for this in android device?

```
elem.bind("input", function(event) {
       var start = elem[0].selectionStart;
       if(start == 1 && event.currentTarget.value.charAt(start-1)==" "){
       var value = event.currentTarget.value.trim();
       event.currentTarget.value = value;
       elem[0].setSelectionRange(0, 0);
    }
}
```

And yes if I don't use setSelectionRange it moves the caret to the end.

Answer (score 1):

i had the same problem, i used this advice and it worked for me
[Why the setSelectionRange can't work on android 2.3 platform browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10978825/why-the-setselectionrange-cant-work-on-android-2-3-platform-browser)

try wrapping your "setSelectionRange" with 
"setTimeout with an interval of 0"

tha't should fix your problem.

for example:

```
   var start = elem[0].selectionStart;
   if(start == 1 && event.currentTarget.value.charAt(start-1)==" "){
   var value = event.currentTarget.value.trim();
   event.currentTarget.value = value;
   setTimeout(() => elem[0].setSelectionRange(0, 0),0);
}
```